# How to animate invoking of n subviews with time interval

Tags: ios, swift, animation, view

I need add to my view n subviews with time interval and than set them corner radius also with time interval. 
Problem is that they all together invoke selfs without time interval (immediately) .

I tried Timer.sheduledTimer and GCD but I have no result.
Maybe I did something wrong
Please tell some idea what to do

```
func addSubviews(count : Int, completeon : (_ view : UIView)->()) {
    view.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
    for i in 1...count {
        let inscribedView = UIView()
        inscribedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let sizeConstant = ((self.screenWidth / 2 ) / self.viewsCount )
            self.view.addSubview(inscribedView)
        //setup constraints
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: inscribedView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: CGFloat(count == viewsCount ? statusBarHeight + sizeConstant * i : sizeConstant * i)))
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: inscribedView, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: -CGFloat(sizeConstant * i)))
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: inscribedView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -(CGFloat)(count == self.viewsCount ? self.tabBarHeight + sizeConstant * i : sizeConstant * i)))
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: inscribedView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: CGFloat(sizeConstant * i)))

        inscribedView.backgroundColor = RandomFlatColor()
    }

       completeon(view)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.becomeFirstResponder()


}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    viewWillLayoutSubviews()
}
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    addSubviews(count: viewsCount) { view in
        for subview in view.subviews {
                subview.addCornerRadiusAnimation(from: 0, to: 20, duration: 0.3)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you calling viewWillLayoutSubviews after viewWillAppear?

Comment: I have a tab bar and I need i redraw subviews if I going through tabs

Comment: You are messing with the vc delegate methods, I dont think its a good idea, just call your animate with `view.layoutIfNeeded()`, not calling the delegate method again

Comment: can you please add the screenshot of the views that you intend to have ?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following for animating in a bunch of views with different timings:

```
    let views:[UIView] = [view00,view01, view02]
    let timing:[Double] = [0.806,0.816,0.826]
    for (index,view) in views.enumerated() {
        //set any view properties that will be animated to starting state
        view.alpha = 0
        // animate each view
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.28, delay: timing[index], options: .curveEaseOut, animations:  {() -> Void in
        //set the final view properties that are animateable here
            view.alpha = 1
        }, completion: {(finished:Bool) -> Void in
            //can set off a second animation here
        })
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I write it in  "for i in 1...count " cycle but everything is still

Comment: remember to set a starting state, then in the animation block put the ending state ( I will update the answer with a comment to that effect ) Constraints are animatable, iirc, but there can be some issues with them. You may need   references to your views outside of the method creating them.